# How should I turn a list of coordinates in python to a matrix representing what pixels should be displayed?

Tags: python, matrix, bitmap, coordinates, data-conversion

Here's my code:

```
    def coorsToDataMatrix(xs, ys, density, range, pixelCounting=True):
        maxX, minX, maxY, minY = range
        width = int((maxX - minX) * density)
        height = int((maxY - minY) * density)

        if pixelCounting:
            data = np.zeros((height, width), dtype=int)
            for x, y in zip(xs, ys):
                data[-int((y-minY)*density)][int((x-minX)*density)] += 1
        else:
            data = np.zeros((height, width), dtype=bool)
            for x, y in zip(xs, ys):
                data[-int((y-minY)*density)][int((x-minX)*density)] = True

        return data
```

It just takes in two numpy arrays of x and y coordinates and returns a 2d matrix of either booleans values(whether the pixel should be displayed) or int values representing the density of value near that pixel.

The objective is to display "data" with matplotlib.pylot.imshow()

Does anyone have a suggestion on how to improve it? I've had some problems processing a lot of points. On a related note, are there any other ways to store a bitmap-like object in python other than numpy matrix?